# EasyUI version 1.3.6 not send queryParams

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, panel, jquery-easyui

I recently upgraded my EasyUI library to v1.3.6 because it allows me to load panels (and dialogs, etc..) using the POST command. For some reason though, it will not send the queryParams with the request. Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong.

This loads in my global js file:

```
$.extend($.fn.panel.defaults, {method:'post'});
```

Then I call the Dialog like so:

```
var row = grid_users.datagrid('getSelected');
if( row )
{
    var dialog = $('#dialog_users').dialog({
        href:post_panel('admin','users','dialog_edit'), 
        queryParams:{userid:row.userid},
        closed:false,cache:false,modal:true,
        title:'Edit User',width:400,height:300,
        buttons:[ {
            text:'Edit',iconCls:'icon-edit',
            handler:function(){ $('#form_edit').submit(); }
        },{
        text:'Cancel',iconCls:'icon-no',
            handler:function(){ dialog.dialog('close'); }
        } ],
        onLoad:function() { 
            $('#form_edit').form({
        url: 'index.php?/admin/users/update/edit/'+row.userid,
        onSubmit: function() { return $(this).form('validate'); },
        success: function(result) {
            var result = eval('('+result+')');
        if (result.errorMsg)
            $.messager.show({title:'Error',msg:result.errorMsg});
        else 
        {
            dialog.dialog('close');
                        grid_users.datagrid('reload');
        }
        }
    });
        },
        onBeforeClose:function() { $('#form_edit').form('clear'); }
    });
 }
```

I can confirm with chrome dev tools that the call is a POST call and it is sending it to the correct url. It is not sending the `userid` like I want it to. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: did you find the solution.am also facing the same problem

Comment: Same problem here. If I define method and queryParams in dialog options, it doesn't work !